# How to implement the methods of the interface IEnumerable< >?

Tags: c#

If I have this code:

```
public class Pilota < T > {
  public T Current {
    get;
    set;
  }
  private T NamePilota {
    get;
    set;
  }
  private T SurNamePilota {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public List < T > pilota;
  public Pilota(int NumberPilota) {
    pilota = (new T[NumberPilota]).ToList();

  }
  public void Add(T name) {
    pilota.Add(name);

  }
}
```

How do I implement the methods of the interface? I need because I wanted to use the Foreach loop.

Should I create the MoveNext, Reset, and Current, right? But how do I?

Comment: have you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Just return the `List<T>`'s enumerator.

Comment: [Read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx). `IEnumerable<T>` needs to implement `GetEnumerator` and it's the `IEnumerator<T>` returned by that method that will need to implement `MoveNext`, `Reset`, etc.

Comment: Your code seems to be confusing the concept of a single pilot with that of a list of pilots. Why don't you simply use `List<Pilota>` instead of sticking the list in the `Pilota` class?

Comment: Yes, of course, on MSDN but it doesn't seem the same

Comment: And, for the most part, you might find it easier to just inherit from `List<T>` rather than im plement all of `IEnumerable<T>` yourself. But if you really need to wrap a `List<T>` rather than inherit from it, you should at least make the wrapped list private or protected.

Answer (score 0):

make this extends the "IEnumerable" interface and override the "GetEnumerator" method using the `yield` keyword:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach (T elem in pilota) yield return elem;
}
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand what would this line of code:  `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();}`

Comment: .NET 1.0 does not support generics. This non-generic version of the iterator is used to provide backward compatibility.